# Meteor 1.3 install on Windows 7 says it's installed but windows doesn't recognize meteor as a command

Tags: meteor

Was able to run the earlier versions of Meteor.  Does anyone have any solution?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Windoze ... turns out it installed after running for about ten minutes.   Hope this is of some use to someone.